# Flutter - Keyboard does not appear and does not stay under the chosen field

Tags: dart, flutter

Keyboard is not working properly with `TextField`.

The code below I put 14 `TextField`, but when clicking for example in field 14 the keyboard does not appear and it is not below the `TextField` tapped.

Could you help me with this keyboard problem not showing up and not getting me under the chosen field to be?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 1',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 2',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 3',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 4',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 5',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 6',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 7',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 8',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 9',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 10',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 11',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 12',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 13',
                ),
              ),
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type something 14',
                ),
              ),             
            ],
          )          
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem a few days ago - does the keyboard appear if you put the app in the background and then in the foreground again? (And then click on a `TextField` again?). I know this does not help you at all, but it would be interesting to see if it's the same behavior...

Comment: @david.mihola But how i do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not have all your text fields sharing the same `TextEditingController`. Use a separate controller for each one.

Comment: Thank you the keyboard appeared!!! But fields 11 to 14 because they are the last ones they are behind the keyboard. Is it possible to leave the keyboard under the selected field?

Comment: It sounds like you're running into https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10826, which has a workaround posted on the issue until a final fix is in place.

Comment: Thanks, your code in https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/50172e3547e959cba77e2938f2fe5ff5 worked perfectly (in line 57 I increased to 600ms). Would you know when the definitive solution would come?

Comment: I'm not sure at this time.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, but in my case it was in Key object

```
await showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) {
      final _textKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Load conference'),
        content: Form(
          key: _textKey,
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            validator: (str) {
              if (str.isEmpty) {
                return 'Empty url';
              } else if (str.length >= 4 && str.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase() != 'http') {
                return 'Url has to start from \'http\'';
              }
            },
          ),
          onChanged: () {
            if (controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
              _textKey.currentState.validate();
            }
          },
        ),
```

Problem was solved by making key static class field

```
static final _textKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Comment: The keyboard works fine. But I get this exception in console log "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey."

Answer (score 3):

Move your Globalkey creation out of you build function.

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _profileScaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _profileScaffoldKey,
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue after modifying android **app level gradle** file updating both my **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to **28** from the default (**27**). Consider leaving it to the default version. I was testing on an android 9 emulator with google play store.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the error, everything seems to work fine. Check if your **Flutter SDK** is updated (run `flutter doctor`). Have you tried to change the target platform to IOS to see if the error persists?

Comment: I do not have mac and iOS. Did you try to play on iOS?

Comment: I tried and everything went fine too. You can "mimic" IOS behavior by setting a custom TargetPlatform in your app theme. Try to use another keyboard and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the key of the form. In my case, I was experimenting this issue because I had a deprecated version of the form in the project structure which uses the same key. Form keys must be unique. Once I commented out the deprecated version the keyboard started working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

To make the keyboard below to textFormFeild use attribute:
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true , in Scaffold Widget.